# Browser automatically adds a numerical suffix to the file name when opening a file via FTP

Tags: browser, ftp, csv

I am trying to keep the filename identical when I open a .CSV file that is accessed via FTP.

For example, If I try to open the .CSV file "SampleDL.CSV" that is saved on my hard drive, Chrome and Internet Explorer both open a file titled "SampleDL.CSV". But if I have get the file via FTP from a device titled "SampleDL.CSV", it will open in my browser, but will be called "SampleDL[1].CSV". If I open it again, it will still have that [1] suffix on the file. This PC is running Windows 7

I have another PC where I tried the exact same thing, but the filename never changes, which is what I want. The only difference is that the PC is running Windows 10.

Is there a setting in Windows FTP setup that does this? Is it a setting in Internet Settings? Is it the operating system?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's not because there is already a file with that name in your downloads folder so the browser is appending the number to differentiate it?

Comment: I am positive.  It shows up, only when I try to import it.  The place I am importing it from only has one version, and so does the temporary area where it saves on my hard drive. Also, when my PC has a duplicate file, its suffix is (1), not [1]. I have managed to detect and clip it off of the file name, but I'd prefer it just not happen.